# Como estilizar vários elementos com diferentes estilos no hover

Tags: html, css, css-hover

Eu tenho uma `div` com vários links, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde no `hover` da `div` (wrapper) fazia apenas o underline do `bold text` (title) mas ao fazer `hover` nas `tags` fazia o underline da respetiva tag e não fazia underline ao `bold text`. Deixo embaixo um esquema de como está feito e o código que até agora tenho para melhor entendimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está a cinza é o wrapper, a vermelho o `bold text` que quero `underlined` assim que o cursor estiver no wrapper, a azul é a div (.tags) e a laranja são as tags que quando o cursor passar por elas sublinhar a respetiva. Já tenho o `hover` do wrapper a funcionar porém não estou a conseguir fazer a parte das `div's`, o title aparece sempre `underlined`.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 35px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1% 0 0 1%;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .wrapper:not(.tags):hover { 
  text-decoration: underline;
 }

 .wrapper a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 .tags {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26%;
  right: 2%;
 }

 .tags a:hover .wrapper {
  text-decoration: none !important;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <a href="#">
  <b>Title</b>
  <div class="tags">
   <a href="#">Tag1</a>
   <a href="#">Tag2</a>
   <a href="#">Tag3</a>
  </div>
 </a>
 <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mudei apenas uma parte do seu CSS Bruno, mas acho que você também poderia melhorar a formatação do HTML. Segue o exemplo:

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper > a, .tags a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.wrapper:hover > a, .tags a:hover {
     text-decoration: underline;
}
.tags {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26%;
    right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <b>Title</b>
    <div class="tags">
      <a href="#">Tag1</a>
      <a href="#">Tag2</a>
      <a href="#">Tag3</a>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Se não for exatamente o que vc precisa me fala que eu arrumo o código pra vc.